# How do I see what SQL Enttity Framework SaveChages is generating?

Tags: entity-framework-4

There often are times when I would like to see what SQL is being generated by EF. For instance I query an object, modify it and save it back:

```
var context = new EntityModel();
var MyObj = context.FooTable.First(o => o.id = SearchId);
MyObj.Property = SomeValue;
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get some silly error that I may be able to troubleshoot if I could see the SQL. I am far from a EF expert and it would help me learn too.

**Update:** I think what I really want to know is: In auto-tracking EF objects as shown above, how do I get at the ObjectContext/ObjectQuery to use ToTraceString() to see what was executed in SaveChanges()?

Comment: This article might be interesting to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx

Comment: With SQL Express Profiler, you can just view the SQL for certain things. Under the Events tab, I set SPStmtCompleted and nothing else. This captures selects, updates and inserts from the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I use the free [SQL Express Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)

Comment: I also use this. Works very well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like pretty easy task but it is not because ADO.NET team somehow forgot to include such basich functionality. Check [EF Tracing provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers). That is something which can help you log SQL commands. Otherwise go with SQL Profiler and learn how to use filters when establishing new trace.

Answer (score 0):

the [EF Profiler](http://efprof.com/) is a great tool for this - its not free though :(